# POST request is empty using ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I do a POST request to my server's route, the `request.body` is empty. And I'm using body parser to obtain JSON data. What I'm doing wrong?

On the `_saveTicket` function, I have `console.log` to show all the body request parameters. And when I do a POST request, `request.body` is empty.

What I need to parse it automatically ?

**server.js**

```
/**
 * Declaration
 **/
var     express   = require('express'),
        database  = require('./config/database.js'),
        morgan    = require('morgan'),
        port      = 2559,
        bodyPar   = require('body-parser'),
        methodOv  = require('method-override'),
        mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
        fsr       = require('file-stream-rotator'),
        logDirectory = __dirname + '/log',
        favicon   = require ('serve-favicon');
        app       = express();

/**
 * DB Connection
 **/
mongoose.connect(database.mongo);

/**
 * Api definition
 **/
 var accessLogStream = fsr.getStream({
   date_format: 'YYYYMMDD',
   filename: logDirectory + '/access-%DATE%.log',
   frequency: 'daily',
   verbose: false
 })

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));
app.use(bodyPar.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyPar.json());
app.use(bodyPar.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(methodOv('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));

/**
 * Routes section
 **/
require('./routes/ticket.js')(app);

/**
 * Starting server
 **/
app.listen (port)
console.log ("Listening on port: " + port);
```

**model/ticket.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TicketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title:          String,
  description:    String
}, {versionKey: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema, 'Ticket');
```

**routes/ticket.js**

```
var Ticket = require('../models/ticket');

module.exports = function(app){

   _getAllTickets = function(req, res){
    var query = Ticket.find().lean();

    query.exec(function(err, lst){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(lst);
    });
  };

  _saveTicket = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);

    var tckt = new Ticket({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description
    });

    tckt.save(function(err){
      if(!err)
        console.log('Ticket creation successful. ');
      else
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    });

    res.send(tckt);
  };

  app.get('/api/tickets/', _getAllTickets);
  app.post('/api/tickets/', _saveTicket);
}
```

Comment: Is it a multi-part POST?

Comment: What happens when you console.log the req.body?

Comment: It shows `{}`, an empty object @dward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the HTTP request has the `Content-Type` header set to be `application/json` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` based on your `body-parser` middleware definitions. My guess is that its coming through right now as neither of those `Content-Type`'s

Comment: When I do a curl using shell, I get the right body using this command `curl -XPOST http://localhost:2559/api/tickets/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "title" : "[Video] No lol, no party "  }'`

Comment: But If I use postman to do the request, I can't obtain body. And I have the right headers.

Comment: Can you `Generate Code` from  Postman as `NodeJS > Request` and post as part of your question?

Comment: I solved, you're right. The problem was the header, it was setted to `text/plain`. Thanks you mate !